# Editing assets on the fly App Model

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, assets

There are many times when I have a solution deployed and would like to change something in the CSS or JavaScript without having to go through a full deploy again. With Farm Solutions, you can open the web in SharePoint Designer or directly in the browser, make client side modifications, save and see you changes right away.

Developing in the app model, I can't seem to connect to the App Web's assets. I've tried hitting /_layouts/viewlsts.aspx, connecting via SPD and navigating directly to the /Scripts or /Content libraries. I am denied access through each technique.

Is there a  way to modify files on the fly when deploying a solution using the App model?

Answer (score 0):

The App Web was specifically designed to prevent you from doing what you want to do. The App Web site template, the App Web master page, and the AppLockdown Feature are all designed to prevent users from accessing the internals of the App.

For more information watch [An overview of developing SharePoint-hosted apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/SharePoint-Conference/2012/SPC010) starting at 52:45.

Comment: That's too bad. There should be a Dev mode because it's not very efficient when testing JS to redeploy and re authenticate for every small code change. I just finished your course in PluralSight Rob, good job man!

Comment: You finished it already? It was just published yesterday.

Comment: Oops, just the first module I guess

Comment: Oh, OK. Well I'm glad you're enjoying it so far.